# Get the change of dimensions on resize using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For my web site I am using the following code:

```
$(window).resize(function (event) {
    window.location.reload();
});
```

Unfortunately when using the site on a mobile device there are minute resize events that occur. I am wanting to put in a tolerance so that these minute changes do not fire this reload.For this I need to know the change in dimensions that occurred in the resize event. I have been looking at the `event` object however it is huge and ugly.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: All you need to do is use a media query

Comment: That will not get to the root of this problem @JBDouble05 Please read the question

Comment: But what I mean is that you should just use a media query so that your function does not occur if you're on a mobile device. That's my first idea

Comment: That is a fair point. However I want it to fire on decent sized resize events no matter the screen size

Comment: But how would you resize it on a mobile device?

Comment: @JBDouble05, certainly switching of page orientation would lead to window resize.

Comment: Very good point @Arvind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the helpful comments of [JBDouble05](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10221765/jbdouble05) and the helpful answer by [Dacre Denny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8526705/dacre-denny) I have made a final solution that fits my needs. Here it is to help others in the future hopefully.

```
var OGwidth = $(window).width();
var OGheight = $(window).height();
var threshold = 50;
$(window).resize(function (e) {
    if (OGwidth < 768) {
        var newWidth = $(window).width();
        var newHeight = $(window).height();

        var widthChange = Math.abs(OGwidth - newWidth);
        var heightChange = Math.abs(OGheight - newHeight);

        if (widthChange > threshold || widthChange > threshold) {
            window.location.reload();
        }

    } else {
        window.location.reload();
    }
    //reset for next resize
    OGwidth = newWidth;
    OGheight = newHeight;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this by tracking the original window dimensions and then comparing those dimensions with current dimensions (acquired during each resize event) to determine the amount of change.

The following shows how you could trigger a reload if the width changes by a certain total `THRESHOLD` amount:

```
var THRESHOLD = 50; // the threshold that must be exceeded to trigger reload

$(window).resize(function(e) {

  var width = $(window).width();

  // Record the starting window width that the comparison will
  // be relative to
  if(window.startWidth == undefined) {
    window.startWidth = width;
  }

  // Calculate the total change since first resize event
  var widthChange = Math.abs(width - window.startWidth);

  // If change exceeds THRESHOLD, trigger reload
  if(widthChange > THRESHOLD) {
    window.location.reload();
  }

})
```

Comment: This won't work because the line `var width = $(window).width();` gets the new width so you are comparing the new width with the new width. I need to get the old width somehow

Comment: Hi @Worm , it only does so in the first resize event. Notice how `window.startWidth` is stored once, and then reused as a reference width to detect the threshold? Or perhaps I'm missing something here ?